# Coming from notification causes crash

Tags: android

I have a problem with searchview.If user comes from notification,my app is crashing.

This is my `onResume`

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    String userId = getIntent().getStringExtra("username");
    if(userId != null) 
    { 
        userId=userId+jidDomain;
        startChat(conversationsMap.get(userId));
    }
}
```

In `startChat` method following line 1015 causes **nullPointerException**

```
searchView.setIconified(true);
```

I am setting `searchView` inside this method:

```
    @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
            SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(SEARCH_SERVICE); 
            searchView = (SearchView)searchItem.getActionView();
...
```

This is happening only if user comes from notification.If user starts app normally this isn't happening.

Crash report:

```
01-14 00:31:49.211: E/AndroidRuntime(19507): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.impact.app/com.impact.app.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-14 00:31:49.211: E/AndroidRuntime(19507):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2790)
01-14 00:31:49.211: E/AndroidRuntime(19507):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2819)
01-14 00:31:49.211: E/AndroidRuntime(19507):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2266)
01-14 00:31:49.211: E/AndroidRuntime(19507):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-14 00:31:49.211: E/AndroidRuntime(19507):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
01-14 00:31:49.211: E/AndroidRuntime(19507):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-14 00:31:49.211: E/AndroidRuntime(19507):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-14 00:31:49.211: E/AndroidRuntime(19507):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
01-14 00:31:49.211: E/AndroidRuntime(19507):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-14 00:31:49.211: E/AndroidRuntime(19507):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-14 00:31:49.211: E/AndroidRuntime(19507):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
01-14 00:31:49.211: E/AndroidRuntime(19507):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-14 00:31:49.211: E/AndroidRuntime(19507):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-14 00:31:49.211: E/AndroidRuntime(19507): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-14 00:31:49.211: E/AndroidRuntime(19507):    at com.impact.app.MainActivity.startChat(MainActivity.java:1015)
01-14 00:31:49.211: E/AndroidRuntime(19507):    at com.impact.app.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:380)
01-14 00:31:49.211: E/AndroidRuntime(19507):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1192)
01-14 00:31:49.211: E/AndroidRuntime(19507):    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5211)
01-14 00:31:49.211: E/AndroidRuntime(19507):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2780)
01-14 00:31:49.211: E/AndroidRuntime(19507):    ... 12 more
```

Comment: most likely this is from onResume() running prior to onCreateOptionsMenu().

Comment: 1015:searchView.setIconified(true);

Comment: @JeffreyBlattman What do you suggest ?

Comment: only call `startChat()` after you get the search view in `onCreateOptionsMenu()`?

Comment: How can i do this ? I put invalidateoptionsmenu above startchat but nothing changed

Comment: post more code... searchView may be getting set null somewhere or another problem. You assume the problem is in the lines you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (searchView != null) {
      chatStarted = true;
      startChat(...);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  ...
  searchView = (SearchView)searchItem.getActionView();
  if (!chatStarted) {
    chatStarted = true;
    startChat(...);
}
```